# trying to get a project in visual studio 2015 to use a txt.file in the project instead of using a usb drive

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a program that I have working great.  It is using a txt file from e:\inventory to run. Is there a way I can add this to the project so that the code will run without accessing the usb drive?

I have added it to the project by right clicking on the project name and adding a new item (text file) and this added it in soulution explorer.  However, I can not seem to figure out how to tell the code to look there for the file.

Currently my code says:

```
    Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strLocationAndNameOfFile As String = "e:\inventory.txt"
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim intFill As Integer
    Dim strFileError As String = "The file is not available.  Restart when the file
        is available."

    '   Verify the file exists.
    If IO.File.Exists(strLocationAndNameOfFile) Then
        objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strLocationAndNameOfFile)
```

Comment: Select the file in the Solution Explorer and in it's properties set it to `Copy if newer`. Then just remove `e:\ ` from your path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just reference the file by name if it's in the same directory as your executable.

1. In your solution explorer, select the text file and then look at the properties window (right click on the text file and select "properties" if the window isn't already displayed.
2. In the properties window, change the "Copy to output directory" value to "Copy if newer"
3. Change your code to reference the file by name without a path

   Dim strLocationAndNameOfFile As String = "inventory.txt"

Comment: That is wonderful. thank you so very much. That has been driving me nuts.